# Exponentially weighted function in $ \mathcal L_1 $?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have an interesting adaptive control problem.

Consider a signal $u(t)$ generated by normalizing another signal, so that
$$
0 \leq u(t) < 1.
$$
Consider the function generated from $u(t)$ as follows
$$
g(t) = u^2(t) e^{-\gamma \int_0^t u(s) ds}.
$$
The question is; is $g(t)$ in $ \mathcal L_1$? (That is, is the integral $ \int_0^\infty g(t) dt $ finite?)
One is free to choose $ \gamma > 0 $ as large as one wants, but it cannot depend on any information in $ u(t) $ (since it is not measured).

I would be very happy for a proof, or just hints on how to proceed for a proof.
Thanks a lot!